# Contact images not showing after update to 4.7.7

Tags: wordpress, contact-image

I just upgraded my civicrm install from 4.6.10 to 4.7.7 and moved the main page in wordpress to another subdomain. It was at www.site.com/civicrm and now it is at www.site.com/somethingelse/civicrm. Since I executed these actions contact images are not showing anymore. I updated the civicrm-settings.php file to add the new subdomain as the standard page and noticed that civicrm started working with dynamically generated paths [civicrm.root] and [civicrm.files]. I also tried to fill out the absolute paths to the file locations and civicrm confirmed that the locations were found. Still no pictures. Removing an image and re-upload it also does not solve the problem. Anybody else having the same experience, is it a bug or am I missing some settings? thanks.Running WP 4.5.1